# I need my .NET Framework 4.7.2 website to be able to use the authentication of my .NET Core Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

To get an overview, I have an old .NET Framework 4.7.2 Website with a lot of .aspx Files and I have a new .NET Core WebApp. Both are running on the same server under the same domain with different ports.

I now want to login into the .NET Core Website and be able to use the Authentication Token on the .NET Framework Website too.
I tried to use the Cookie generated by the .NET Core Website to Authenticate on the .NET Framework Website with Owin, but I couldn't find any way to get this to work.

Does anyone have an Idea on how to accomplish this? I need to authenticate once and be able to stay Authenticated over both websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share authentication cookies between your ASP.NET 4.x applications and your ASP.NET Core applications, firstly, configure the ASP.NET Core application by following the steps:

1. Add Authentication to your app

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
        services.AddAuthentication();
        //other services...
   }
   ```
2. In your `Configure` method use the `CookieAuthenticationOptions` to set up the data protection service for cookies

   ```
   app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
   {    DataProtectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\shared-auth-ticket-keys\"))
   });
   ```

Then configure your ASP.NET 4.7.2 application by following steps below:

1. Install the package `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Interop` into  your ASP.NET 4.7.2 application.
2. In `Startup.Auth.cs`, locate the call to `UseCookieAuthentication`, which will generally look like the following:

   ```
   app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
   {
       // ...
   });
   ```
3. Modify the call to `UseCookieAuthentication` as follows, changing the `AuthenticationType` and `CookieName` to match those of the ASP.NET Core cookie authentication middleware, and providing an instance of a DataProtectionProvider that has been initialized to a key storage location.

   ```
   app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
   {
       AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
       CookieName = ".AspNetCore.Cookies",
       // CookiePath = "...", (if necessary)
       // ...
       TicketDataFormat = new AspNetTicketDataFormat(
           new DataProtectorShim(
               DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\shared-auth-ticket-keys\"))
               .CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
               "Cookies", "v2")))
     });
   ```

**The DirectoryInfo has to point to the same storage location that you pointed your ASP.NET Core application to and should be configured using the same settings.**

4. In `IdentityModels.cs`, change the call to `ApplicationUserManager.CreateIdentity` to use the same authentication type as in the cookie middleware.

   ```
   public ClaimsIdentity GenerateUserIdentity(ApplicationUserManager manager)
   {
       // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
       var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity(this, "Cookies");
       // ...
   }
   ```

Reference:

[Share authentication cookies among ASP.NET apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

[Share authentication cookies between ASP.NET 4.x and ASP.NET Core apps](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/21987)